# Compiling Monogame Shaders on MacOS - preloader: Warning: failed to reserve range 0000000000010000-0000000000110000

Tags: c#, monogame, wine

I recently got a new mac and I'm setting up wine to compile shaders as [this link](https://docs.monogame.net/articles/getting_started/1_setting_up_your_development_environment_macos.html#optional-set-up-wine-for-effect-compilation) says. I had to edit the mgfxc_setup.sh file to account for it downloading a 32-bit version of the SDK, but even before then I was getting the same problem (on top of the one I fixed). Everytime I try to compile shaders, I get the following output:

```
...
/Users/foo/Documents/GitHub/bar/Content/Shaders/light_effect.fx
/Users/foo/Documents/GitHub/bar/Content/Shaders/light_effect.fx: preloader: Warning: failed to reserve range 0000000000010000-0000000000110000
preloader : warning : failed to reserve range 0000000000010000-0000000000110000 [/Users/foo/Documents/GitHub/bar/bar.csproj
...
```

It then repeats the "preloader : warning : failed to reserve range" line for roughly another 12 lines.

I've been googling around to figure it out, but I can't find anything about this problem specifically. Just googling the error message gets a lot of wine crossover related stuff. Any ideas?